# Spark Dataset.groupBy as input to Spark ML Pipeline.fit

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, databricks, apache-spark-ml

Given: A big `Dataset` (1 billion+ records) from a DeltaTable on Databricks

I want to partition this `Dataset` in +- 1000 different partitions, dependent on some properties of each record. Then, I want to `fit` a Spark ML `Pipeline` for each of these partitions.

My first idea would be to use `Dataset.groupByKey`, and then `mapGroups`. However, the latter function provides me an `Iterator` instead of a `Dataset`. `PipelineModel.fit` only accepts a `Dataset` as input.

```
dataset.groupByKey(item => (item.propertyOne, item.propertyTwo))(product)
  .mapGroups((key, group) => {
     val pipeline: Pipeline = // ...
     pipeline.fit(group) // Doesn't work since group is of type Iterator, not Dataset
   })(product)
  .foreach(_.save(some_path))
```

The alternative implementation I have now is to iterate and each time `filter` on the original `Dataset`, which I then pass to the `PipelineModel.fit` method. This works, but is awkwardly slow. I played around with multithreading this, but to no avail.

```
// 1000 possible values
allPossiblePropertyValues.forEach { v =>
  pipeline.fit(dataset.filter(_.property == v)).save(some_path)
}
```